# Google Glass search in language other than English?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have looked through the web and not found any information about if the Google Glass will have speech recognition in other languages than English? Like Google Now for example has a fine working recognition for Swedish.

Or do I need to implement some third-party recognition myself?

If anyone in the Google Glass Team has this info, this would be nice to know!

Thanx
Joakim

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on the team, but the usual response is that the focus right now is the US only and that they don't comment on future plans.

There are a lot of legal/regulatory issues to deal with before Glass can be supported in other countries, and they're still dealing with those issues in the US. They *have* demonstrated Glass to non-US government leaders, but not announced any formal support in those countries.

It is certainly expected that they will support Glass internationally, just like they support other products where possible, but that there is no indication when that support will be available.

Comment: Just as I suspected then... Will be looking into third-party solutions then. Thanks.

Comment: When you are saying third-party solutions you are referring to what exactly? I have the same problem: I want to do speech recognition on french. Can you give me an example of third-party solution to do speech recognition in french? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to implement speech recognition on Google Glasses:

http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home

Easy to implement and to start with.

Regards
Joakim