# Change language of offline speech recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-glass

I have succesfully integrated offline speech recognition into my glass app by following these steps: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168267/glass-voice-command-nearest-match-from-given-list/21251558#21251558).

But I couldn´t find a possibility to change the language for recognition. Is there any or is it impossible?

(The Language files have to exist somewhere, maybe I just can replace them for another language, when there is no better possibility.

I guess it uses the files from data/data/com.google.glass.voice/files)

Answer (score 0):

This question was answere here : [Available Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500805/google-glass-search-in-language-other-than-english)

I saw that there is only US and EN language for now in XE 21, and Google didn't communicate about new language yet.